# Carl von Clausewitz in original German

Tags: translation, history, reference-request

Though I'm sure this is simpler than I'm making it I've been unable to find the German original of the Carl von Clausewitz quote

> Next to victory, the act of pursuit is most important in war.

I don't have access to (and can't find online) a copy of the original text.

Comment: Looking at the original, *victory* seems not to be the best translation for *Schlagen*; I guess *combat* is closer to the intention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original seems to be:

> Das Verfolgen aber ist im Kriege nächst dem Schlagen das Wichtigste.

This isn't from "Vom Kriege" ("About War") but from a work dating in 1812: "*Die wichtigsten Grundsätze des Kriegführens zur Ergänzung meines Unterrichts bei Sr. Königlichen Hoheit dem Kronprinzen*" ("Principles Of War"). There is an [English translation](https://www.clausewitzstudies.org/mobile/principlesofwar.htm) available online including a link to the [German version](https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/view/clausewitz_krieg03_1834?p=224). The quote can be found on [page 229](https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/view/clausewitz_krieg03_1834?p=243).